# How to load JSON Data on google visualization Chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm new with google-visualization. I'm developing a full dashboard like [google full dashboard example](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#full_dashboard)

Following the example I declare data like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['CodiceCliente', 'Cliente', 'QtàO13', 'QtàO14','UM'],
        ['0000038893', 'Coop',300,350, 'CT'] .... ]);
```

Now I want to load data from server. I create a Json like this:

```
{
"cols": [
    {"id": "codiceCliente","label": "Cod. Cliente","type": "string"},
    {"id": "clienteDesc","label": "Cliente","type": "string"},
    {"id": "qtaO13","label": "Qtà O13","type": "number"},
    {"id": "qtaO14","label": "Qtà O14","type": "number"},
    {"id": "um","label": "UM","type": "string"}
       ],
"rows": [
    {
        "c": [
            {"v": "0000038893"},
            {"v": "Coop"},
            {"v": "300"},
            {"v": "350"},
            {"v": "CT"} ]
        }, 
        {.... }, ... ]}
```

In html page i use this code to get data from server:

```
 var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getJson.do",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
  var data = google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

When I open the page, I get this error: " Object # has no method 'zg' at format+it,default+it,ui+it,controls+it,corechart+it.I.js:183 "

where am I wrong? JSON format is wrong?

Comment: I find this functionality confusing, myself. I find the easiest way to test this: take the `DataTable` you've generated with the `arrayToDataTable` call, call `toJSON` on that `DataTable`, and compare the output from it to the input you've generated. The differences are likely where your errors are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `new` keyword in the DataTable constructor.  It should be:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```