# Laravel trouble getting data for google chart when using paginate function

Tags: javascript, laravel, pagination, google-visualization

I have this query where I get my data by using pagination:

```
$data = Mymodel::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);
```

And I have no problems to display the data in a bootstrap table with its pagination links within a blade file:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>value1</th>
                <th>value2</th> 
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($data as $row)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $row->value1 }}</td>    
                    <td>{{ $row->value2 }}</td>                  
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>

        {{ $data->links() }}
```

Now when setting up a google line chart:

```
@section('js')
    {{--Google charts--}}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'],'language': 'es'});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLinechart);

        function drawLinechart()
        {

            var record = {!!$data!!};
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();/*http://stackoverflow.com/a/22640426/1883256*/
            var rowsnumber = record.length;

            //Declaring the column names
            data.addColumn('number', 'ID');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value1');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value2');          

            //Filling each row. Ref:http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861051/1883256
            $.each(record, function(k, v) {
                //display the key and value pair
                //console.log(k + ' is ' + v.id);
                data.addRow([v.id,parseInt(v.value1),parseInt(v.value2)]);
            });

            var options = {
                title: 'Data last '+ rowsnumber +' rows',
                //curveType: 'function',
                backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'},
                height: 500,
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },              
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

        {{-- end of Google charts--}}
@endsection
```

This does not work because it turns out that paginate inserts html code for the pagination links, since I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

And this is because the `$data` outputs:

`var record = <ul class="pagination">` ... and so on ... instead of the Eloquent's collection. It outputs actually a `LengthAwarePaginator`.

Then how do I access the data (`$row->id`,`$row->value1`,`$row->value2`)
right in the javascript section?

On the other hand, this does work if I get the data through another query variable:

```
$datachart = Mymodel::orderBy('id','desc')->take(30)->get();
```

which is in fact a collection. In other words, this is working:

```
var record = {!!$datachart!!};
```

But what I really want is to chart the data along with the pagination so that in every page I can output the corresponding values in the linechart.

Any ideas on how to access the collection data in javascript right from a LengthAwarePaginator?

**Workaround**:
I get another collection with the same query but without the pagination and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var record = {!! $data->data !!};
```

I think paginator stores data in a `data` object inside the `response` object.

Comment: Nice try ... but I get the following error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$data`

Comment: do a `dd($data)` from your controller.  And show the result here. Please. And also be aware the second `data` doesn't have a `$` in front.